# Adding information to Python dictionary from user input variables

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been searching for an answer for this assignment for about 2 days.  I've found may issues similar but none that really answer the issue.  I'm sure it is something simple but I'm returning to school after a 18 year break.  I am trying to add an item to a dictionary from user input where we are making a grocery list.  I keep overwriting my data instead adding to it in the dictionary.  I can add it to the list fine.  For reference here is my code:

```py
grocery_item = {}
grocery_history = []
#Variable used to check if the while loop condition is met
stop = True
choice=0
grand_total=0
item_total=0

while stop == True:
    current_item = {}
    current_item["name"]=(input('Item name:\n'))
    current_item["quantity"]=int(input('Quantity purchased:\n'))
    current_item["cost"]=float(input('Price per item:\n'))

    grocery_history.append(current_item)
    grocery_item.update(current_item)

    print('Would you like to enter another item?')
    choice=str(input("Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n"))

    if choice == 'c':
        stop = True
    else
        stop = False

    #grand_total=0
    #item_total=0

    for i in range(len(grocery_item)):
        item_total=(grocery_item['quantity']*grocery_item['cost'])
        #print("--------")
        #print(grocery_item)
        #print(grocery_history)
        #print("--------")

        grand_total+=item_total

        #Output the information for the grocery item to match this example:
        #2 apple    @   $1.49   ea  $2.98
        print(grocery_item['quantity'],"",grocery_item['name'],"@","$",grocery_item['cost'],"ea","$" (item_total))


print("Grand total: $", grand_total')

#Set the item_total equal to 0

item_total=0
```

For the experienced programmers sorry for the '#' but I've been trying to test to see where I am messing up.

Here is what I get:

```
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
4  onions @ $ 0.79 ea $ 3.16
4  onions @ $ 0.79 ea $ 3.16
4  onions @ $ 0.79 ea $ 3.16
Grand total: $ 9.48
```

And here what I am supposed to get:

```
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
1 milk @ $2.99 ea $2.99
2 eggs @ $3.99 ea $7.98
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
Grand total: $14.13
```

I've determined that grocery_history list is correct but grocery_item dictionary is just being overwritten by the last entry.

It seems to be Python 3.x from some of the code I've been able to use that is supposed to be 3.x.

Comment: post you input data

Comment: It looks like your indentation is off. The scope of the `while stop == True:` loop should end at the assignment to `stop`. So the code that comes after that should be outdented, otherwise it gets executed as a part of the loop whether `stop` is true or false.

Comment: I would recommend using debugger+breakpoints+evaluate expression to test your code instead of using prints...It's much more efficient and revealing. You get an up vote for your effort, good luck with your return.

Answer (score 0):

> Some working code here for you :)

```
stop = True
grocery_history = []
grocery_item = {}
grand_total = 0
#current_item has gone

while stop == True:

    #setdefault helps you to add new values as a list for the existing keys
    grocery_item.setdefault("name",[]).append(input('Item name:\n')) 
    grocery_item.setdefault("quantity",[]).append(int(input('Quantity purchased:\n')))    
    grocery_item.setdefault("cost",[]).append(float(input('Price per item:\n')))

    print('Would you like to enter another item?')
    choice=str(input("Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n"))

    if choice == 'c':
        stop = True
    else: 
        stop = False

        #This loop helps to iterate sufficiently for given item names 
        for i in range(len(grocery_item['name'])): 

            item_total=(grocery_item['quantity'][i]*grocery_item['cost'][i])
            grand_total+=item_total
            print(grocery_item['quantity'][i],"",grocery_item['name'][i],"@","$",
                  grocery_item['cost'][i],"ea","$",(item_total))
            # This part creates a history item for each sale for the given item names and append it to the grocery_history
            ith_history = [str(i+1)+'.Sale: '+str(grocery_item['quantity'][i]) + ' ' +grocery_item['name'][i] + ' from ' + 
                           str(grocery_item['cost'][i])+' Total: ' +str(item_total)]
            grocery_history.append(ith_history)

print("Grand total: $", grand_total)
#Set the item_total equal to 0
item_total=0
```

> `grocery_item.update(current_item)` just updating your dictionary keys and values
>   with latest given keys and values, you have different values but same keys each time, that's why you have grocery_item with only latest inputs.
>
> `for i in range(len(grocery_item))` will iterate 3 times all the time
>   regardless of the input, because len(grocery_item) = 3 ('name',
>   'quantity', 'cost'). That's why you had 3 lines of `4  onions @ $ 0.79 ea $ 3.16` although you had only 1 item in grocery_list.

And here is your expected output with this code:

```
1 milk @ $2.99 ea $2.99
2 eggs @ $3.99 ea $7.98
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
Grand total: $14.13

grocery_history
[['1.Sale: 1 milk from 2.99 Total: 2.99'],
 ['2.Sale: 2 eggs from 3.99 Total: 7.98'], 
 ['3.Sale: 4 onions from 0.79 Total: 3.16']]
```

I wish you success in school after 18 years :)

Comment: Thank you.  The site that we use currently will not allow me in.  It may be down again.  I did not know that there was a debug function in Python.  I will defiantly have to use that.  I am in an into class but would like to learn more and become much more proficient in Python because it seems very versatile and good language to learn.  Is there any sites or books anyone would recommend that is good at explaining the language that anyone has had experience with?